# SQL join and add row values as column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help.

Given 3 tables

Table name 1: Table1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike |
| 2 | John |

Table name 2: join1

| ID | column | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | job_description | manager |
| 1 | salary | 3000 |

Table name 3: join2

| ID | column | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hobby | cycling |
| 1 | Date of join | 12.01.2020 |

output should join Table1 where ID=1 and join both tables Join1 and Join2 with row as column name "job_description" from join1 and with 2 rows as columns  "Hobby" and "salary" from join2 table like so:

| ID | name | job_description | Hobby | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | manager | cycling | 3000 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can join all three tables according to your criteria. For example:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.value, c.value
from table1 a
join join1 b on b.id = a.id and b.column = 'job_description'
join join2 c on c.id = a.id and c.column = 'Hobby'
where a.id = 1
```

As a side note, the table names (`join1`, `join2`) can be a bit confusing as entity names. The column names (`column`, `value`) may be too generic, but this is up to your database design.

**EDIT**

For the updated question, you want to retrieve multiple row values of the secondary table for the same row in the main table. The typical solution is using aggregations or subqueries. Using the latter the query can take the form:

```
select a.id, a.name, 
  (select value from join1 b where b.id = a.id
     and b.column = 'job_description') as job_description,
  c.value as hobby,
  (select value from join1 b where b.id = a.id
     and b.column = 'salary') as salary
from table1 a
join join2 c on c.id = a.id and c.column = 'Hobby'
where a.id = 1
```

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to add 1 column to my output, how it is to solve, if I need more than 1 row from third table (join2) to my output?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  id
       ,t.name
       ,"'job_description'" as job_description
       ,t3."value"          as Hobby
       ,"'salary'"          as Salary
from    t2
pivot   (max("value") for "column" in('job_description',  'salary')) p join t using(id) join t3 using(id) 
where   "column" = 'Hobby'
```

| ID | NAME | JOB_DESCRIPTION | HOBBY | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | manager | cycling | 3000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-dnBd-yK)

Comment: See updated answer